# How to use a razor declared variable outside of razor?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, razor

I have a foreach displaying product descriptions and product prices. i want to be able to sum all of the prices and display them in a data cell. How can i do this?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@product.Description</td>
                <td>@product.Price</td>
            </tr>
        }

        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {
            var sum = product.Price++;
        }

        
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Total Price:   </td>
            </tr>
      

    </table>
```

i want to be able to show the value of sum outside the foreach

Comment: Just declare it before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable inside a code block and use it in the foreach like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

@foreach (var product in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@product.Description</td>
    <td>@product.Price</td>
  </tr>
}

@{
   var sum = 0;
   foreach (var product in Model)
   {
      sum += product.Price;
   }
}

    
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Total Price: @sum</td>
  </tr>
  

</table>
```

An alternative could be `using System.Linq`.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Total Price: @Model.Sum(product => product.Price)</td>
</tr>
```